# how to ignore IllegalArgumentException: no mapping found for field when using suggester with elasticsearch 5.5

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch-5

how to ignore IllegalArgumentException: no mapping found for field when using suggester with elasticsearch 5.5

In elasticsearch 2.4, I could get 0 hits when running the following query, though there wasn't my_field in mapping:

```
http://192.168.99.100:9200/myindex/_search
{
  "suggest" : {
    "my_field-suggestions" : {
      "text" : "na",
      "completion" : {
        "field" : "my_field"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
{
    "took": 30,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 1,
        "failed": 4,
        "failures": [
            {
                "shard": 1,
                "index": "myindex",
                "node": "PSP1qvhZRwy-FWMqt-p72A",
                "reason": {
                    "type": "exception",
                    "reason": "Field [my_field] is not a completion suggest field"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 0,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    },
    "suggest": {}
}
```

However in elasticsearch 5.5.3, I got a error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                "reason": "no mapping found for field [my_field]"
            }
        ],
        "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
        "reason": "all shards failed",
        "phase": "query",
        "grouped": true,
        "failed_shards": [
            {
                "shard": 0,
                "index": "myindex",
                "node": "Y0UrN9N3RCW7vpWiH0tvtw",
                "reason": {
                    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                    "reason": "no mapping found for field [my_field]"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

In Java program, how to handle this exception?

```
Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[Y0UrN9N3RCW7vpWiH0tvtw][common_customer][0]: RemoteTransportException[[Y0UrN9N][172.18.0.5:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[no mapping found for field [my_field]]; }{[Y0UrN9N3RCW7vpWiH0tvtw][common_customer][1]: RemoteTransportException[[Y0UrN9N][172.18.0.5:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[no mapping found for field [my_field]]; }{[Y0UrN9N3RCW7vpWiH0tvtw][common_customer][2]: RemoteTransportException[[Y0UrN9N][172.18.0.5:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[no mapping found for field [my_field]]; }{[Y0UrN9N3RCW7vpWiH0tvtw][common_customer][3]: RemoteTransportException[[Y0UrN9N][172.18.0.5:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[no mapping found for field [my_field]]; }{[Y0UrN9N3RCW7vpWiH0tvtw][common_customer][4]: RemoteTransportException[[Y0UrN9N][172.18.0.5:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[no mapping found for field [my_field]]; }
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.onPhaseFailure(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:271)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.executeNextPhase(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:129)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.onPhaseDone(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:240)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.InitialSearchPhase.onShardFailure(InitialSearchPhase.java:88)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.InitialSearchPhase.access$100(InitialSearchPhase.java:47)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.InitialSearchPhase$1.onFailure(InitialSearchPhase.java:156)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListenerResponseHandler.handleException(ActionListenerResponseHandler.java:51)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$ContextRestoreResponseHandler.handleException(TransportService.java:1067)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$DirectResponseChannel.processException(TransportService.java:1171)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$DirectResponseChannel.sendResponse(TransportService.java:1149)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$7.onFailure(TransportService.java:655)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.onFailure(ThreadContext.java:623)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:39)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: NotSerializableExceptionWrapper[: no mapping found for field [my_field]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[no mapping found for field [my_field]];
    at org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.guessRootCauses(ElasticsearchException.java:618)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException.guessRootCauses(SearchPhaseExecutionException.java:170)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException.getCause(SearchPhaseExecutionException.java:111)
    at org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.writeTo(ElasticsearchException.java:285)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException.writeTo(SearchPhaseExecutionException.java:61)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.StreamOutput.writeException(StreamOutput.java:838)
    at org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.writeTo(ElasticsearchException.java:285)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.ActionTransportException.writeTo(ActionTransportException.java:64)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.StreamOutput.writeException(StreamOutput.java:838)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.sendErrorResponse(TcpTransport.java:1147)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransportChannel.sendResponse(TcpTransportChannel.java:76)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.DelegatingTransportChannel.sendResponse(DelegatingTransportChannel.java:70)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry$TransportChannelWrapper.sendResponse(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:123)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.HandledTransportAction$TransportHandler$1.onFailure(HandledTransportAction.java:77)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.raisePhaseFailure(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:219)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no mapping found for field [my_field]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.suggest.SuggestionBuilder.populateCommonFields(SuggestionBuilder.java:308)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.suggest.completion.CompletionSuggestionBuilder.build(CompletionSuggestionBuilder.java:358)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.suggest.SuggestBuilder.build(SuggestBuilder.java:174)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:660)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createContext(SearchService.java:481)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createAndPutContext(SearchService.java:457)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:253)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchTransportService$6.messageReceived(SearchTransportService.java:330)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchTransportService$6.messageReceived(SearchTransportService.java:327)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry.processMessageReceived(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:69)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$7.doRun(TransportService.java:644)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:638)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
    ... 3 more
```

I'm using spring-data-elasticsearch in spring boot project.

Answer (score -1):

While creating indexes in elastic search you have to specify a key value pair of data. The key should be the field name where your are about to search. Please put in more info about the data inside elastic search.

ElasticSearch:
`http://localhost:9200/{index}/_all/_mapping/`

should return you the below kind of data. The field NAem should be mentioned in

```
{
  "indexName": {
    "mappings": {
      "typeName": {
        "properties": {
          "<Field Name>": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The key question is that in the mapping I don't have the field name and don't want to set it up. In 5.5 and 2.4, their behaviors are different